# Write an outline for a proof of this statement

Tags: logic, proof-writing, solution-verification

[image]

I am a bit stuck on this problem,
for this outline I so far have:

Let a∈R, n∈Z be arbitrary.

Let there be some N∈Z.

Assume n>N.

I am not sure how to continue this outline for the proof though.

Comment: Doesn’t seem true to me.

Comment: Thank you, I am a bit stuck on how to go about writing down a proof for that however.

Comment: I agree with @ThomasAndrews; take $a<2$; then no matter how big $N$ is, there is an odd number $n>N$ and $|(-1)^n-1|=2\not\lt a$

Comment: @J.W.Tanner I think $a=2$ fails too

Comment: @Henry:  I agree that I could have said $a\le2$, though any $a<2$ demonstrates by counterexample that the statement is not true